# Mongoose compare property array size with other property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is it possible to find all the documents that have the size of one property (which is array) greater/less than other property (which is a number)? *We assume that inside schema numberProperty is of type Number and array is holding ObjectIds.*

I mean something like:

```
Collection.find({array: { $size: { $lt: numberProperty} }});
```

---

Triend also something like this, but doesn't work neither:

```
Collection.find({$expr: { $gt: ["$numberProperty", "$array.length"] }});
```

Comment: Is the number you need to compare against static? e.g. `myArrayProperty.length > 3`

Comment: It's a number, but it's a property of the same object that includes the array, so... it's not a static number, but a variable.

Comment: Please share sample input and expected output

Comment: I used general names for purpose of the example, but I just pass names of properties inside the condition. Expected output are the Id's of object, that's why in real app I added :  .distinct("_id") to only get the Id's of objects instead of whole objects, but the idea is the same

Comment: Sorry, not able to understand. Would be great if you can share sample document which I can insert in my local db and then expected result of the query against which I can test the query.

Comment: Okey, will do it in about 1 hour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202356/discussion-between-kamil-turowski-and-invider).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an aggregation

```
Collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { $expr: { $gt: [ {$size: "$array"}, "$numberProperty" ] } } }
]);
```

If that doesn't work, try first projecting the array size into a new field and then doing the comparison

```
Collection.aggregate([
    { $project: { arraySize: {$size: "$array"}, numberProperty: 1 } },
    { $match: { $expr: { $gt: [ "$arraySize", "$numberProperty" ] } } }
]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: None of those two ways seems to work in my example :/

Comment: Hmm that’s weird. If you remove the `$match` stage from the 2nd option, does the `arraySize` field get projected properly (has the right values)?

Comment: `{ $match: { $expr { $gt: [ {$size: "$array"}, "$numberProperty" ] } } }`